# Cumulative incidence plot in R using ggsurvplot

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to create a cumulative incidence plot that also gives me a risktable at specified time points, has confidence intervalls and censor marks. The structure of my data is like this:

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(survminer)
library(tidycmprsk)
library(prodlim)
library(cmprsk)

time = c(1:10)
status = c(T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F)
df <- data.frame(time, status)
```

Censor time is in days and in status T = event, F = no event. The original data also includes NAs.

I almost get the result that i want with this:

```
ci_surv <- Surv(time, status)
ci_survfit <- survfit2(ci_surv ~ 1)

ggsurvfit(ci_survfit) +
  labs(
    x = "Days",
    y = "Event-free proportion"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 5, 10)) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  add_censor_mark()
```

But obviously instead of the event-free proprtion (survival) I would like to get the cumulative incidence displayed on the y-axis.

I tried several of other solutions already. One gives me a correct plot:

```
plot(ci_survfit,
     fun = function(Surv) 1-Surv,
     atrisk.title="Number at risk",
     atrisk=T)
```

but this gives me "not a graphical parameter" error for basically anything that I want to add to the plot like atrisk as above.

The same is true for this solution:

```
ci_cuminc <- cmprsk::cuminc(time, status)
plot(ci_cuminc, atrisk = T)
```

where atrisk also doesn´t work.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: When you see the "not a graphical parameter" message you should have realized that you had stumbled outside the cozy environs of the tidyverse. You should also note that in this case it was not an error but rather a warning. The `plot` method for `survfit` objects, which gets called because `survfit2` is actually a wrapper for `survival::survfit`, uses base plotting functions and does NOT use ggplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type = "risk"` in `ggsurvfit`

```r
ggsurvfit(ci_survfit, type = "risk") +
  labs(
    x = "Days",
    y = "Event-free proportion"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 5, 10)) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  add_censor_mark()
```

[image]

Or you can use `ggcuminc` from the ggsurvfit package, which is specifically for plotting cumulative incidence:

```r
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)

time = c(1:10)
status = c(T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F)
df <- data.frame(time, status)

df$status <- factor(df$status)

cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = 'TRUE') +
  labs(
    x = "Days",
    y = "Cumulative incidence"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 5, 10)) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  add_censor_mark()
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding this solution can you share how you change aesthetics for these plot (for example line color and line type)? Thanks